# How do I get a speed boost at the start of a race?

Tags: sonic-all-stars-racing-transformed

What is the timing for getting a speed boost at the start of a race in *Sonic & All-Stars Racing Transformed*? I've noticed the AI getting speed boosts, but I haven't been able to figure out how to get one myself.

Answer (score 1):

Tap the accelerator (right trigger button by default) on each beat of of the countdown, when the announcer yells each number and the Go at the end.  This will get you up to three stages of boost, although mistiming a button press will cause you to lose the boost entirely.

Comment: The timing seems to be just *before* the announcer says the number. Tapping the accelerator when the screen goes dark before each number has given me the most consistent results.